# Pip hangs on Ubuntu 21 Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pip

Tried a few times and it can hang for the whole night.
[image]

Comment: Probably quickest to ask Ubuntu about this problem.

Comment: Please do not post pictures; just cut-and-paste the text.